# Why is Map#getOrDefault not more generic?

Tags: java, collections

I am writing a consumer of a `Map<K, ? extends V>`. The map has some subtype of `V`, but I just deal in `V`. I want `getOrDefault` to return a `V`, and I want to supply a default that is a subtype of `V` that might be different than the value type of the map. I wrote this method to get what I want:

```
static <K, U, V extends U, W extends U> U getOrDefault(
    Map<? super K, V> map, K key, W defaultValue)
{
    final U value = map.get(key);
    return (value == null) ? defaultValue : value;
}
```

Any reason this wouldn't have worked as the original specification of `getOrDefault`?

Comment: Why would `U` not always be `Object`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman If `V` is `Integer` and `W` is `Long`, then `U` is `Number`, the nearest common supertype.

Comment: @Andreas Who says it's the nearest common supertype?  What if there are multiple common supertypes, such as several interfaces in common?  Why isn't `U` `Serializable`?

Comment: John, not reason, other than it not making a lot of sense for a value coming out of a `Map<?, Integer>` to return anything other than `Integer`, whether that is `get`, `getOrDefault`, `put`, `remove`, `replace`, `compute`, `computeIfAbsent`, or `computeIfPresent`.

Comment: (Note also that `Collections.unmodifiableMap(map).getOrDefault(k, value)` lets you get away with this safely.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Sorry, you're right. It can be. Both works: `Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(); Number a = getOrDefault(map, "", 1L); Serializable b = getOrDefault(map, "", "");`

Comment: `Map` doesn't have a `getOrDefault)` method. `ConcurrentMap` does. It takes an `Object` parameter for the key for the same reason that `Map.get()` does, or to be symmetric with it.

Comment: @EJP [`Map#getOrDefault(..)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) since 8, but yes on everything else.